# What files to give my Client for their Logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

I took graphic design in school years ago, but have been out of the loop for quite some time. I recently created a vector logo for a friend for their business. I am wondering how to save the files so they have no background around the logo and so they can put on any form for print and rescale it to whatever size they wish. I also would like to give them one for their website. What would you recommend- and how to save it properly if you have specific instructions? I have saves a successful png for web use withough background... as well as an .ai file.

Comment: Also http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/55102/23061

Answer (score 2):

First off, send a copy of the original vector should they need to alter the dimensions, otherwise save PNG-24's of each of the sizes below (PNG's for the transparency, but it does make images a raster format) . I would recommend you give a small logo size (maybe around 150px X 150px) for the site header, the size of a standard piece of A4 paper, and a size between those (you choose the size for that one). Also, optionally, you may want to include a huge blown up one for the sake of posters.

Worst comes to worst, just ask the client, better safe than sorry.