# How to choose company logo resolution?

Tags: logo, file-format, file-size, image-format

I am currently finishing logo in Photoshop. 
Logo will be used in Instagram header(or whatever it's called) and also will be printed on all kinds of different stuff of various sizes.

I need an advise on what would be a reasonable resolution/file size to save logo when passing it to customer?

Comment: finishing logo, in photoshop, asking for reasonable resolution. This will be a smarkastig remark but read a book first. None of this things should happen when crating logo.

Comment: also answered here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55102/industry-standard-file-format-deliverables-for-logos

Comment: Logos should not be created in Photoshop.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Photoshop for the creation of logos. It's the wrong kind of software.  Better to use a vector image editor if you want to print at various sizes.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I have to disagree: finishing a logo is something that should absolutely happen.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet after that we just call it rebranding :)

Answer (score 6):

If the logo lends itself to vector format, and (arguably) it should, then you'd be better off designing it in a vector editing program (like Illustrator) and not having to worry about the resolution at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. You should not use PhotoIShouldNotUseItForLogosShop

Your logo is now limited to the fixed size you made it.

> resolution/file size to save logo

This also has no sense. Resolution is not a parameter to take into account. Resolution is just a metadata on a file.

File size has no sense either. A parameter is never "a 1 Mbyte file".

> will be used in an Instagram header

Here is the only place there is a specific image size. A simple google search: "Instagram Logo Size" says 110x110px.

https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=instagram+logo+size

> also will be printed on all kinds of different stuff of various sizes

**You need to remake the logo on a vector based program. Corel Draw, Illustrator, Affinity designer or Inkscape.**